# Expo AuthSession for FB login not redirecting to expo App for some versions of Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, react-native, expo

I am having an issue with authSession from Expo and Facebook Login. Facebook Login works on iOS and my Android Phone. However there seems to be a redirect problem with some Android Phones.
Here is the FB Login flow in phones where it does not end up completely redirecting to the app
[image][image]
[image]

Here is my App.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Scapegoat",
    "icon": "./app/images/logo.png",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "sdkVersion": "23.0.0",
    "facebookAppId": "1XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "facebookScheme": "fb1XXXXXXXX",
    "scheme": "exp",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.scapegoatllc.scapegoatmobile"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.scapegoatllc.scapegoatmobile",
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my facebook button press function where I make use of AuthSession,

```
onFacebookButtonPress = async () => {
//const FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'; // -> develop
const FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // -> staging

const redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
//exp://exp.host/@newtonsarr/scapegoat

const { type, params } = await AuthSession.startAsync({
  authUrl:
    `https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?response_type=token` +
    `&client_id=${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}` +
    `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}`,
});

if (type === 'success') {
  this.props.onLoginWithFacebook({ access_token: params.access_token });
}
};
```

Is there anything wrong with my current set up ? How do I make sure that Facebook Login always redirects back to the App? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: hello, this is a difficult question to answer on here because given the information that you provided it is possible that it is a bug. can you dm me slack.expo.io? i am "brent" on there.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect url is wrong try to log it first, 
It would be in the format of `https://auth.expo.io/@username/appname`